# Order List<T> by given pattern with Trie

Tags: c#, search, pattern-matching, trie

I'm currently trying to implement a structure in C# to sort a generic list by a given pattern.
The entry which has the best "score" gets on top of the list, the second entry has the second most scores and so on.

Example:

- Search pattern: "Fac"
- List with objects, each object has the property "title":
- Lets say, the objects have got the titles "Facebook", "Family Fall", "Fall"

When searching, the object with the title "Facebook" should be on top of the list, the second object would be "Family Fall", because it has the pattern "Fa" twice in its title.

Is there any way to implement such a structure in C#?
I tried to look for several algorithms, I even started with a Trie structure, which currently looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sprung
{
    class WindowTrieNode : IComparable<WindowTrieNode>
    {
        private String pattern;
        private Char character;
        private List<WindowTrieNode> followers;

        public WindowTrieNode(String pattern, Char character)
        {
            this.pattern = pattern + character;
            this.character = character;
            this.followers = new List<WindowTrieNode>();
        }

        public void addFollower(WindowTrieNode follower) {
            if(!hasFollower(follower.getChar())) {
                this.followers.Add(follower);
            }
        }

        public bool hasFollowers()
        {
            return !this.followers.Any();
        }

        public bool hasFollower(Char character)
        {
            if (!hasFollowers()) return false;
            WindowTrieNode node = new WindowTrieNode(this.pattern + character, character);
            return this.followers.Contains(node);
        }

        public WindowTrieNode getFollower(Char character)
        {
            WindowTrieNode node = new WindowTrieNode(this.pattern + character, character);
            if (hasFollower(character)) return followers.ElementAt(this.followers.IndexOf(node));
            return null;
        }

        public Char getChar()
        {
            return this.character;
        }

        public int CompareTo(WindowTrieNode n) {
            // Not yet implemented.
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Would this be a correct approach? Are there better approaches and solutions?
Thanks alot.

Another approach would be the [Approximate String Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)